# javascript the opacity sometimes changes(randomly) after the animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have two animations, one is 'transition' that zooms out an image on hover and the other is the animation2 in which the opacity of the image changes repeatedly at periodic intervals.

I have animation2 going on over an image and when I hover over it, the animation2 stops and transition happens that makes the image remain zoom till I am hovering over it and when I get away from it, the animation2 does not take its place.

The problem is when transition takes place, sometimes its image has opacity 0.3 and sometimes 1.I want it to remain 1 after animation2 stops.Any suggestions?

```
(function pulse (back) {
    $('#img1').animate ({
        'font-size': (back) ? '100px' : '140px',
        opacity: (back) ? 1 : 0.3
    }, 500, function () {pulse(!back)});
})(false);
$('#img1').hover(function () {
    $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
    $("#img1").addClass('transition');
    (function pulse (back) {
        $('#img1').animate ({
            'font-size': (back) ? '100px' : '140px',
            opacity: (back) ? 1 : 1
        }, 500000, function () {pulse(!back)});
    })(false);
}, function () {
    $("#img1").removeClass('transition');
});
```

Comment: why is the line "opacity: (back) ? 1: 1," not effective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think you had a few problems with your function. This should work:

```
(function pulse (back) {
    $('#img1').animate ({
        'font-size': (back) ? '100px' : '140px',
        opacity: (back || $("#img1").hasClass('transition')) ? 1 : 0.3
    }, 500, function () { pulse(!back)} );
})(false);

$('#img1').hover(
    function () {
        $("#img1").addClass('transition');
    },
    function(){
        $("#img1").removeClass('transition');
    }
);
```

And here's a jsfiddle to show it working: http://jsfiddle.net/G848k/

- I have removed the line which added the CSS style `cursor:pointer` as that can be set in the CSS and will always apply only on hover.
- I have removed the re-declaration of your function `pulse()` as you don't want to be redeclaring the function.
- On your original `pulse()` function I have added to the inline if statement on the opacity to check whether ther div `#img1` has the class "transition" and if so to always set it to 1.

Hope that's what you wanted.

---

Update based on your comment.

Try this:

```
function pulse (back) {
    if(!$("#img1").hasClass('transition')){
        $('#img1').animate ({
            opacity: (back) ? 1 : 0.3
        }, 500, function () { pulse(!back)} );
    }
}

(function (back){
    pulse (back);
})(false);

$('#img1').hover(
    function () {
        var element = $("#img1");
        element.addClass('transition');
        element.stop(true, true);
        element.css('opacity', 1);
        element.animate ({
            'font-size': '140px',
        }, 500);
    },
    function(){
        var element = $("#img1");
        element.removeClass('transition');
        element.animate ({
            'font-size': '100px',
        }, 500, function(){
             pulse(false);
        });
    }
);
```

And here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G848k/1/

- I have separated the 2 animations as you only want the zoom when hovering over.
- The pulse function stops repeating while hovering over and restarts on hover off. To make this work I had to create a separate self calling function to start the pulse off.
- The `stop(true, true)` instantly stops the animation and then the `.css('opacity',1)` sets it instantly to 1.

---

Slight update based on further comments. Just removed the line to re-initialise the pulse function going. Also reverted back to previous self calling function for pulse.

```
(function pulse (back) {
    if(!$("#img1").hasClass('transition')){
        $('#img1').animate ({
            opacity: (back) ? 1 : 0.3
        }, 500, function () { pulse(!back)} );
    }
})(false);

$('#img1').hover(
    function () {
        var element = $("#img1");
        element.addClass('transition');
        element.stop(true, true);
        element.css('opacity', 1);
        element.animate ({
            'font-size': '140px',
        }, 500);
    },
    function(){
        var element = $("#img1");
        element.removeClass('transition');
        element.animate ({
            'font-size': '100px',
        }, 500);
    }
);
```

See jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/G848k/3/

Comment: @AndrewPollard the thing is ..in the beginning only opacity and font size and transition does not take place.When I hover over it, opacity should at once become 1 and the transition(zoom out) takes place and when I hover away from it ..the image zooms in but the opacity will remain 1(that means animation2 had stopped after I hovered over it)...The problem is everything works fine in my code except that the opacity sometimes does not remain equal to 1(opacity should not change and which is happening in my code but it should be 1 which is not happening in my code)

Comment: @user3731929 So you only want zoom in on hover over. And then zoom out of hover off. And you want instant opacity change on hover. Is that correct?

Comment: in your example.. the animation2 again begins after hovering away which should not ..can you tell how to prevent that?

Comment: @user3731929 I'm afraid you'll have to be clearer. Please tell me step by step the action that should happen. Currently it is always fading in an out except when hovering over. Font increases size on hover. Font decreases size on hover off.

Comment: once it is hovered over, the opacity should not change ..but in your example(which is pretty good ..almost to what I need) the opacity again starts changing after hovering away from it.